# How can I use different dimension of matrix in a loop?

Tags: loops

This is my input:

```
x1=[1 2 3 4]
x2=[1 2 3 4 1]
x3=[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ]
```

I want to develop a `for` loop code to calculate this equation `D = x1(i+1)-x1(i)`, for example:

```
for i:1:k % k is referring to matrix of x1, x2 and x3
   for i=1:n % n is referring to number of element in matrix x1, x2 and x3
      D= x1(i+1)-x1(i) % for k=2 i want to change x1 to matrix x2
   end
end
```

Can anyone help me how to write the correct code for my problem? I have tried many times, but it failed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow - what language are you writing this in?  Can you also post the programs output and any error messages you get

Comment: Array indexes usually start with zero, not one, unless this is matlab.  What are the values of K & n.

Comment: hi, i am using matlab. actually, i am not very sure what is the correct code. what i want to do is for k=1, which is refer to x1, i want to calculate the " x1(2)-x1(1),x(3)-x(2), x(4)-x(3). n is refer to the element in x1. for k=2, i want to do the same ting on the x2. x2(2)-x2(1), x2(3)-x2(2).......